# java DOM lookupNamespaceURI is not able to locate namespace URI

Tags: java, dom, namespaces

I'm trying to follow http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-nmspccontext/index.html

```
    UniversalNamespaceResolver
```

example for resolving namespaces of the XPath evaluation agains an XML. The problem I encountered is that lookupNamespaceURI call below returns null on the XML, I given below:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    String nsURI = dDoc.lookupNamespaceURI("h");
```

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<h:root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">

   <h:table>
     <h:tr>
       <h:td>Apples</h:td>
       <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
     </h:tr>
   </h:table>`
</h:root>
```

while I'd expect it to return "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When configuring a DocumentBuilder, you have to explicitly make it namespace aware (a silly relic from the first days of xml when there were no namespaces):

```
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

As a side note, the advice in that article is not very good.  it fundamentally misses the point that you *don't care* what the namespace prefixes are in the actual document, they are irrelevant.  you need the xpath namespace resolver to match the xpath expressions that you are using, and that is all.  if you do what they are suggesting, you will have to change your xpath code whenever the document's prefixes change, which is a horrible idea.

Note, they sort of cede this point in their last bullet, but the rest of the article seems to miss that this is the fundamental idea when using xpath.

> But if you don't have control over the XML file, and someone can send you any prefixes they wish, it might be better to be independent of their choices. You can code your own namespace resolution as in Example 1 (HardcodedNamespaceResolver), and use them in your XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks jtahlborn!

The setNamespaceAware helped! I was not aware of that.

As for the other thing - both XPath & XML could be whatever. I have no visibility on what namespaces will be used in there. And, I understand that UniversalNamespaceResolver suggestion will fail at some point when handling different prefixes with same or different namespaces. But I have no idea whatsoever how to handle that properly.

Comment: @user431529 - i don't understand, how can you write xpath for an xml document and _not_ know what namespaces are in use?

Comment: Well, reason is not that obvious: we have a service which receives xpath & xml and is expected to return the result to a legacy system.

Comment: @jtahlborn Imagine a tool that could do mail merge from XML documents. The user would point the tool at a directory of XML customer information documents and provide Xpath queries to find 'Name' and 'Email' in each. The tool would run the xpath queries against each document and generate an email to each customer. I want the user to be able to use namespaces in their xpath, but I don't know when I'm compiling the tool code what those namespaces will be.I want the user to be able to use the same name-space prefixes as the document uses in their xpath queries, does that make sense?

Comment: @PerrynFowler - i can imagine lots of things.  and yes, a program where a 3rd party is entering ad hoc xpath based on what an xml document looks like is certainly the one legitimate use case for a namespace resolver like this.  however, that is one specific use case, and in the large majority of programs, setting the xpath ns prefixes based on what the document looks like indicates a _big_ misunderstanding of how xml namespaces prefixes work.